# Incluir icono con Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind

Estoy tratando de que incluir un icono en uno de mis botones, pero se ve muy mal.

```
<button class="btn-board">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 9v3m0 0v3m0-3h3m-3 0H9m12 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
    New Activity
</button>
```

Y esta es la clase

```
.btn-board {
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #118467;
  color: #118467;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Todo se ve bien, excepto que el icono no esta alineado con el texto. Pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a `.btn-board` añadele `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: @Daniel acabo de agregar el codigo, pero no se vio ningun cambio. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: es porque ya tenes un `display` adentro, saca ese display `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Por otro lado te recomiendo que uses una tipografía de iconos que es menos pesada y mas rápido de usar, te recomiendo que uses [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)

Comment: @Daniel gracias! Funciono bien. El proyecto en el que trabajo ya esta usando los iconos de Heroicons, asi que debo seguir usandolos. Gracias por la buena ayuda